# The user is automatically deleted after a certain period of time

Tags: windows, powershell, active-directory, windows-server-2016

I am enabling write authorization for msDS-KeyCredentialLink in a user property. but after a certain time the user is deleted from the list and disabled again why? I'm doing this for a user account. To test shadow credentials.

For this i add the user here but when i restart it is deleted from here

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpmKS.png

Comment: Your image does not seem to have any correlation with your question.. Why is this a programming question anyway? Did you try to create a powershell solution? If so, please show the code so we can help you with that

Comment: Sounds like [admin account security descriptor propagation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-ds/plan/security-best-practices/appendix-c--protected-accounts-and-groups-in-active-directory#sdprop) working as designed :)

Comment: How can I disable AdminSDHolder?

Comment: You don't. You can update the security description on the AdminSDHolder object to reflect the change you want - although my recommendation would be to _not update the security descriptor at all_. Admin accounts already has write access to the attribute, and granting write access to the attribute to a non-admin account effectively backdoors your domain

Comment: I'm testing this in a virtual machine so it shouldn't be a problem. I still don't quite understand how to do it

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of your earlier question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76748241/deletion-of-the-user-after-a-certain-period-of-time